# A cube in 4 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

> How many corners does a  cube have in 4  dimensions? How many 3D faces? How many edges? A typical corner is $(0,0, 1,0)$. A typical edge goes to $(0, 1, 0, 0)$.

I am solving this question from linear algebra textbook.
I think it will have 16 corners. Am I right? But I cannot figure out how many faces and edges. How does one solve this question using linear algebra.

Comment: Count the number of corners, faces, edges of a cube in dimension $1$, $2$, $3$. Find a formula, and try to generalize it in higher dimension.

Comment: Since the corners have coordinates $0$ or $1$ , there are $2^n$ corners in an $n$-dimensional hypercube.

Comment: HINT: First count how many edges are connected to one vertex. In dimension 1, this is 1. In dimension 2, this is 2. In dimension 3, this is 3. In dimension 4, this is....? Then, given the number of edges connected to a single vertex, how many faces are connected to a single vertex? Once all this is known, can you count across all $2^n$ corners, remembering to discount overlaps?

Comment: Another way to look at it: The hypercube itself consists of all points $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ with $0 \le x_k \le 1$ for each $x_k$. But in its 3-faces, one of the $x_k$ is fixed at one of the extremeties: either $x_k = 0$ or $x_k =1$, while the other three coordinates are still allowed to roam freely. In a 2-face, two coordinates are fixed at either $0$ or $1$, and two are allowed to vary. In a 1-face, that is, an edge, three of the coordinates are fixed and only one is allowed to change. And finally in a 0-face, a vertex, every coordinate is constrained to be either $0$ or $1$.